# Select the Textarea using Button

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to select the  textarea field when user click on button.
My Code:

```
<textarea readonly="readonly"> </textarea> <input type="button" value="Code"/>
```

Jquery Code:

```
 $(function() {

      $(input:button').click(function(){
    ('textarea').select();
  });
});
```

It's not working.

Comment: Does this really your current code? I can't understand your html and there are a lot of misspellings in Jquery part.

Comment: what do you mean by select textarea, do you mean you want the text inside textarea to be selected..?

Comment: please check your codes, did you just copy paste this somewhere?

Comment: Your syntax is bad, but try using $('TEXTAREA').focus() instead of .select()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function(){
    $('textarea').focus();
    $('textarea').select(); //select text inside
});
```

Comment: i think he want to SELECT ALL the contents of the textarea

Comment: you can use select() to select the inner text

Comment: @Sudhir yes I want to select all text inside textbox when I click button

Comment: @Sudhir I am getting error If using this code unexpected end of input